# Slicers are changing width on pivot refresh

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a strange problem. There is a pivot table on separate sheet from the data(Data is a table) and there are about 6,7 slicers for that pivot. When I add new data to Data Table and do "Refresh All" width of the slicers are changing randomly, some get completely closed; you see just one straight line, like width 0. How do I stop that, I want all slicers to stay on the same place and same width.

Comment: go to pivot table settings and uncheck adjust column width on refresh

Comment: @PeterH might as well just make that an answer - not much more to say on the subject

Comment: @AlexM too busy, was just scanning through the site on a little break from work and wanted to help out, feel free to take some screen shots and post as answer yourself if you want to

Comment: @PeterH I do the same, ha. Maybe we can convince OP to do it